# Targetting first element in css <element> + <element>

Tags: css, css-selectors

In css there is the adjacent selector  +  - however does anyone know how I would target the first element in that selector.

i.e. I want to target the `<div>` in the following selector:

> div + p

Thanks in advance

Comment: The simple answer is "you can't". If you show the relevant HTML, we might be able to find a working selector.

Comment: Also, why is purpose of discussing around `div + p`. You can just do anything like `div {..}`

Comment: there is a selector to get the first-child but not for the first element.

Answer (score 0):

If those divs are to be contained inside another element, maybe you could use this selector:

http://w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

```
div:first-child {  background-color:yellow; }
```

So this would "select and style every div element that is the first child of its parent". So, assuming your div was the first child of its parent you could use this. But still, I don't see the practical reason to do this. I'd recommend simply setting a class for those divs and using the class selector.

Comment: `div + p` implies that `div` and `p` share the same parent, and thus `p` *cannot* be the first child.

Comment: Yes, but what the poster is looking for is how to select the <div>. In my answer I just copied the example from the w3cschools link, but I'll edit it for clarity since you mention it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There no css selector for this but you can achieve this some `css & html` manipulation. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
   <p>hover me</p>
   <div>hello</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    -moz-box-orient:vertical;
    -moz-box-direction:reverse;
    display: -moz-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:reverse;
    display: -webkit-box;
    box-orient: vertical;
    box-direction: reverse;
    display:box;
}
p{
    color:red;
}
p:hover + div{
    color:green;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LEh2W/1/

May be that's help you but it's not work in IE.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to assume that the elements are stacked vertically.

Comment: But you get the effect what you want.